# Simple multithreading programing in Python to download file from AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have written this multithreaded program to download files from AWS S3. Kindly review if it is a correct approach.

Code works and downloads the files. But I see an issue occurring sometime (below is the error I see). According to me each file/object from S3 is download independently by one thread. Why would two thread try to access the same file?

**Log:**

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: './Data/weblog_download/web_log_collector_to_s3-1-2020-10-31-10-09-31-cb1494d0-f739-4aa4-a685-9978e0bda090.77C419cA' -> './Data/weblog_download/web_log_collector_to_s3-1-2020-10-31-10-09-31-cb1494d0-f739-4aa4-a685-9978e0bda090'
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: './Data/weblog_download/web_log_collector_to_s3-1-2020-10-30-18-12-14-b8ec4e31-2509-4f16-b5dc-95d3052be92e.0eCEB7B4' -> './Data/weblog_download/web_log_collector_to_s3-1-2020-10-30-18-12-14-b8ec4e31-2509-4f16-b5dc-95d3052be92e'
```

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from AWSUtils import s3_utils
from pathlib import Path
import os, shutil, pprint
import boto3
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import time
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
is_folder_cleanup = True

path_to_save = "./Data/weblog_download"
base_bucket = 'web-logs'
main_key = 'web_logs2020/{}'


def download_file(file_key):
    try:
        
        # getting file name out of the full key (web_log_collector_to_s3-1-2020-10-31-10-09-31-cb1494d0-f739-4aa4-a685-9978e0bda090)
        file_name = file_key.split("/")[-1]
        s3_utils.download_file(base_bucket, file_key, path_to_save + "/" + file_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def download_files_from_s3(key):
    print(f"{os.getpid()}:{threading.current_thread().ident}: Processing: {key}")
    base_kwargs = {
        'Bucket': base_bucket,
        'Prefix': key
    }
    # querying AWS S3 to list all the files/object for the key and bucket.
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(**base_kwargs)
    pprint.pprint(response)
    if response:
        if 'Contents' in response:
            all_files_to_download = []
            # getting each files/object name from the response
            for c in response['Contents']:
                k = c['Key']
                all_files_to_download.append(k)

            # download_pool = Pool(processes=20)
            # download_pool.map(download_file, all_files_to_download)
            # download_pool.close()
            # download_pool.join()

            # using multiple threads to download multiple file/object
            with Pool(processes=5) as pool_thread:
                pool_thread.map(download_file, all_files_to_download)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    today_date = datetime.now()

    days = []
    months = []
    hours = list(range(0, 24))
    keys = []
    # getting day and month for last 7 days and storing into a list
    for i in range(1, 8):
        today_date_minus = today_date - timedelta(days=i)
        day_end = today_date_minus.day
        month = today_date_minus.month
        days.append(day_end)
        months.append(month)

    print(days, months, hours)

    # formatting to get the key/folder as in S3 (web_logs2020/10/26/7)
    for month, day in zip(months, days):
        print(month, day)
        for hour in hours:
            key = main_key.format(f"{month}/{day}/{hour}") # example key -> web_logs2020/10/26/7
            keys.append(key)
    print(f"All Keys: {keys}")
    Path(path_to_save).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # cleaning up current folder to download new files.
    if is_folder_cleanup:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_save):
            print(root, dirs, files)
            for f in files:
                os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
            for d in dirs:
                shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))

    start_time = time.time()
    threads = []
    with ThreadPool(processes=15) as p:
        p.map(download_files_from_s3, keys)

    print(f"Total Time taken: {(time.time() - start_time) / 60}")
```

Comment: `print(f"{os.getpid()}:{threading.current_thread().ident}: Processing: {key}")` look into the `logging` module

Comment: Sure, I always want to use the logger but end up using print.